# Error Jquery no detecta clic en link que muestra ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Con ajax, invoco a un php que muestra una tabla que tiene dos links. Estos Links deben ser detectados con  jquery al hacer el clic. 
Este es el codigo php que muestra perfectamente el listado.

```
<?php hago la conexion y demas ...
echo'
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="6"><i class=" ti-list-ol"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Busquedas  <span class="badge badge-secondary">'.$registros.'</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>                                              
        <th></th>
        <th>Titulo </th>
        <th>Ubicacion </th>
        <th class="Centrado d-none d-md-block">Fecha   -   Vistas</th>                            
        <th></th>                  
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>';
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $AuxConta = $AuxConta + 1;                            
        echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$AuxConta.'</td>
        <td title="'.$row['NombrePuesto'].'">';
        if (strlen($row['NombrePuesto'])>14){
            echo substr(utf8_encode($row['NombrePuesto']), 0, 15)."..";
            }else{
            echo utf8_encode($row['NombrePuesto']);}
            echo'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['UbicacionPuesto'].'</td>';
        echo'<td class="Centrado d-none d-md-block">'.date("d/m/y",strtotime($row['FechaCreacion'])).'  -  '.$row['Visitas'].'</td>';
        echo'<td><i>&nbsp;</i>';
            echo '<a id ="Editando" class="Editador"';        
            echo 'value= "'.$row['IdPuesto'].'"';  
            echo ' href="#" title="Editar Publicacion."><i class="ti-pencil-alt Editar"></i></a>';
            echo'<i>&nbsp;</i>';
            echo'<a id= "ConfirmaBaja" class="ConfirmaBaja" data-idpuesto="'.$row['IdPuesto'].'"'; 
            echo 'data-nombreapuesto = "'.$row['NombrePuesto'].'"';
            echo'data-piebaja="Creada: '.date('d/m/y',strtotime($row['FechaCreacion'])).'"';
            echo 'title="Borrar '.$row['NombrePuesto'].'" href="#"><i class="ti-trash Borrar "></i></a>';                                
        echo'</td>
        </tr>';
     }
echo'</tbody></table>'; ?>
```

Con el siguiente codigo detecto si uno de los items los va a borrar

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.ConfirmaBaja').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var aNombre ='<br>'+ $(this).data('nombreapuesto') + '<br><small class="text-muted ">'+$(this).data('piebaja') +'</small>';
    $('.DatosPublicacionb').html( aNombre);
    $('#BajarID').val($(this).data('idpuesto'))

    $('.LinkBaja').html("<i class = 'ti-alert '></i>&nbsp; Confirmar Baja ");

    $('#ModalConfirmaBaja').modal({show:true});
    //$('#myModalFormPuesto1').[0].reset();        
})
```

});

El tema esta que ese clik de .ConfirmaBaja, no lo detecta.
Este listado antes yo lo habia hecho directamente en el index sin ajax y los clic los detectaba.
Sera que en vez de 
$(document).ready(function(), debo usar otro codigo?
Digo esto porque cuando se dio el Document.ready, el listado no existia, ya que se muestra con ajax despues. No se si logro explicarme. 
debo colocar otro codigo ?
Saludos y mil gracias por la ayuda..!

Comment: La parte del codigo que contiene el listener del click debe ejecutarse despues de que cargues por completo la respuesta de ajax

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta. Escribo el jquery en el mismo php que trae el listado?

Comment: No, si no que cuando ejecutes el ajax que manda llamar el php, una vez que lo recibes, en esta sección de código debes colocar el listener

Comment: Ah ok voy a probarlo graciasss

Comment: Como añadido, es incorrecto tener en el DOM varios elementos con el mismo id. En tu caso llevas a cabo un bucle con echo'<a id= "ConfirmaBaja". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme

Comment: Si si correcto, pero es que yo apunto a la clase. Fijate que invoco al clic en $('.ConfirmaBaja')..!

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste Claudio?

Comment: Hola @jonasdamher si, lo solucione haciendo lo que dijo Jonathan. Coloque el listener en el success del ajax. No me parece muy prolijo, pero funciona.